# Manual pages priority in Emacs

Tags: shell

Emacs provides a nice manual viewer which could be used for obtaining documentation for C syscalls (at point with `Man-default-man-entry`. However, it always starts searching manuals from section 0. How can I configure man viewer so that it will start from section 2, then 3, and then 0?

`man 1 perror` doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs defers to the external `man` command's section choice in the absence of a specific section value.

You can edit the `SECTION` definition in `/etc/manpath.config` to modify the default priority order.

You can override that value with the `MANSECT` environment variable.

Finally, you can override all of that by passing a `--sections=list` option to the command itself.

(See `man man` for details.)

For the final approach, you can set the `Man-switches` variable in Emacs. e.g.:

```el
(setq Man-switches "--sections=2,3,1,n,l,8,3posix,3pm,3perl,5,4,9,6,7")
```

Note that Emacs re-uses man page buffers where possible, so kill the existing buffers before testing this.